# Do dots (...) represent bytes transmitted during a svn commit command?

Tags: svn

I have a big set of new files to synchronize with my svn server. The commit is started, and I see a big number of dots (...) on my terminal. My question is just to estimate how long it can last, provided that I know the size of my files and the number of first dots...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I know it's an old question, but I was searching for its answer today and I found it: the dots should be "One per file whose textual contents are being transmitted".

It doesn't include files with only property modifications or folders, and I'm not entirely sure it includes binaries.